# Play 2.4.0 java.lang.NullPointerException on all http requests

Tags: scala, playframework

I have been building my app with Play 2.4.0 and was working on sorting out some issues with returning errors as Json rather than plain strings.

In the process (unfortunately I have not been 'committing early and often' so I can't bisect to figure out what specific change caused this) I broke something and now when I make any request (even the default GET /, "Welcome to Play", which I haven't changed from the activator template I used) I get this java.lang.NullPointerException that looks like it is happening in the compiler. There are no references to any of my code so I'm having a hard time figuring out what part of my code is triggering this error. It does look like it has something to do with patternmatching, but I am using patternmatching throughout.

Thanks!

```
--- (Running the application, auto-reloading is enabled) ---

[info] p.a.l.c.ActorSystemProvider - Starting application default Akka system: application
[info] p.c.s.NettyServer$ - Listening for HTTP on /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:9000

(Server started, use Ctrl+D to stop and go back to the console...)

[info] Compiling 1 Scala source to /Users/sameer/IdeaProjects/sputnik/target/scala-2.11/classes...
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at scala.tools.nsc.transform.patmat.ScalacPatternExpanders$ScalacPatternExpander$class.applyMethodTypes(ScalacPatternExpanders.scala:64)
    at scala.tools.nsc.transform.patmat.ScalacPatternExpanders$alignPatterns$.applyMethodTypes(ScalacPatternExpanders.scala:90)
    at scala.tools.nsc.transform.patmat.ScalacPatternExpanders$alignPatterns$.apply(ScalacPatternExpanders.scala:132)
    at scala.tools.nsc.transform.patmat.ScalacPatternExpanders$alignPatterns$.apply(ScalacPatternExpanders.scala:153)
    at scala.tools.nsc.transform.patmat.MatchTranslation$MatchTranslator$ExtractorCall$.apply(MatchTranslation.scala:384)
    at scala.tools.nsc.transform.patmat.MatchTranslation$MatchTranslator$BoundTree.extractor$lzycompute(MatchTranslation.scala:71)
    at scala.tools.nsc.transform.patmat.MatchTranslation$MatchTranslator$BoundTree.extractor(MatchTranslation.scala:71)
    at scala.tools.nsc.transform.patmat.MatchTranslation$MatchTranslator$BoundTree.paramType$1(MatchTranslation.scala:113)
    at scala.tools.nsc.transform.patmat.MatchTranslation$MatchTranslator$BoundTree.extractorStep(MatchTranslation.scala:129)
    at scala.tools.nsc.transform.patmat.MatchTranslation$MatchTranslator$BoundTree.nextStep(MatchTranslation.scala:151)
    at scala.tools.nsc.transform.patmat.MatchTranslation$MatchTranslator$BoundTree.translate(MatchTranslation.scala:159)
    at scala.tools.nsc.transform.patmat.MatchTranslation$MatchTranslator$class.translatePattern(MatchTranslation.scala:318)
    at scala.tools.nsc.transform.patmat.PatternMatching$OptimizingMatchTranslator.translatePattern(PatternMatching.scala:89)
    at scala.tools.nsc.transform.patmat.MatchTranslation$MatchTranslator$class.translateCase(MatchTranslation.scala:315)
    at scala.tools.nsc.transform.patmat.PatternMatching$OptimizingMatchTranslator.translateCase(PatternMatching.scala:89)
    at scala.tools.nsc.transform.patmat.MatchTranslation$MatchTranslator$$anonfun$3.apply(MatchTranslation.scala:235)
    at scala.tools.nsc.transform.patmat.MatchTranslation$MatchTranslator$$anonfun$3.apply(MatchTranslation.scala:235)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.map(List.scala:277)
    at scala.tools.nsc.transform.patmat.MatchTranslation$MatchTranslator$class.translateMatch(MatchTranslation.scala:235)
    at scala.tools.nsc.transform.patmat.PatternMatching$OptimizingMatchTranslator.translateMatch(PatternMatching.scala:89)
    at scala.tools.nsc.transform.patmat.PatternMatching$MatchTransformer.transform(PatternMatching.scala:62)
    at scala.tools.nsc.transform.patmat.PatternMatching$MatchTransformer.transform(PatternMatching.scala:57)
    at scala.reflect.internal.Trees$$anonfun$itransform$3.apply(Trees.scala:1379)
    at scala.reflect.internal.Trees$$anonfun$itransform$3.apply(Trees.scala:1379)
    at scala.reflect.api.Trees$Transformer.atOwner(Trees.scala:2600)
    at scala.tools.nsc.transform.TypingTransformers$TypingTransformer.atOwner(TypingTransformers.scala:30)
    at scala.tools.nsc.transform.TypingTransformers$TypingTransformer.atOwner(TypingTransformers.scala:25)
    at scala.tools.nsc.transform.TypingTransformers$TypingTransformer.atOwner(TypingTransformers.scala:17)
    at scala.reflect.internal.Trees$class.itransform(Trees.scala:1378)
    at scala.reflect.internal.SymbolTable.itransform(SymbolTable.scala:16)
    at scala.reflect.internal.SymbolTable.itransform(SymbolTable.scala:16)
    at scala.reflect.api.Trees$Transformer.transform(Trees.scala:2555)
    at scala.tools.nsc.transform.TypingTransformers$TypingTransformer.transform(TypingTransformers.scala:44)
    at scala.tools.nsc.transform.patmat.PatternMatching$MatchTransformer.transform(PatternMatching.scala:73)
    at scala.tools.nsc.transform.patmat.PatternMatching$MatchTransformer.transform(PatternMatching.scala:57)
    at scala.reflect.api.Trees$Transformer$$anonfun$transformTrees$1.apply(Trees.scala:2559)
    at scala.reflect.api.Trees$Transformer$$anonfun$transformTrees$1.apply(Trees.scala:2559)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.loop$1(List.scala:173)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.mapConserve(List.scala:189)
    at scala.reflect.api.Trees$Transformer.transformTrees(Trees.scala:2559)
    at scala.reflect.internal.Trees$class.itransform(Trees.scala:1347)
    at scala.reflect.internal.SymbolTable.itransform(SymbolTable.scala:16)
    at scala.reflect.internal.SymbolTable.itransform(SymbolTable.scala:16)
    at scala.reflect.api.Trees$Transformer.transform(Trees.scala:2555)
    at scala.tools.nsc.transform.TypingTransformers$TypingTransformer.transform(TypingTransformers.scala:44)
    at scala.tools.nsc.transform.patmat.PatternMatching$MatchTransformer.transform(PatternMatching.scala:73)
    at scala.tools.nsc.transform.patmat.PatternMatching$MatchTransformer.transform(PatternMatching.scala:57)
    at scala.reflect.internal.Trees$class.itransform(Trees.scala:1347)
    at scala.reflect.internal.SymbolTable.itransform(SymbolTable.scala:16)
    at scala.reflect.internal.SymbolTable.itransform(SymbolTable.scala:16)
    at scala.reflect.api.Trees$Transformer.transform(Trees.scala:2555)
    at scala.tools.nsc.transform.TypingTransformers$TypingTransformer.transform(TypingTransformers.scala:44)
    at scala.tools.nsc.transform.patmat.PatternMatching$MatchTransformer.transform(PatternMatching.scala:73)
    at scala.tools.nsc.transform.patmat.PatternMatching$MatchTransformer.transform(PatternMatching.scala:57)
    at scala.reflect.internal.Trees$class.itransform(Trees.scala:1366)
    at scala.reflect.internal.SymbolTable.itransform(SymbolTable.scala:16)
    at scala.reflect.internal.SymbolTable.itransform(SymbolTable.scala:16)
    at scala.reflect.api.Trees$Transformer.transform(Trees.scala:2555)
    at scala.tools.nsc.transform.TypingTransformers$TypingTransformer.transform(TypingTransformers.scala:44)
    at scala.tools.nsc.transform.patmat.PatternMatching$MatchTransformer.transform(PatternMatching.scala:73)
    at scala.tools.nsc.transform.patmat.PatternMatching$MatchTransformer.transform(PatternMatching.scala:57)
    at scala.reflect.internal.Trees$class.itransform(Trees.scala:1370)
    at scala.reflect.internal.SymbolTable.itransform(SymbolTable.scala:16)
    at scala.reflect.internal.SymbolTable.itransform(SymbolTable.scala:16)
    at scala.reflect.api.Trees$Transformer.transform(Trees.scala:2555)
    at scala.tools.nsc.transform.TypingTransformers$TypingTransformer.transform(TypingTransformers.scala:44)
    at scala.tools.nsc.transform.patmat.PatternMatching$MatchTransformer.transform(PatternMatching.scala:73)
    at scala.tools.nsc.transform.patmat.PatternMatching$MatchTransformer.transform(PatternMatching.scala:57)
    at scala.reflect.api.Trees$Transformer$$anonfun$transformTrees$1.apply(Trees.scala:2559)
    at scala.reflect.api.Trees$Transformer$$anonfun$transformTrees$1.apply(Trees.scala:2559)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.loop$1(List.scala:173)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.mapConserve(List.scala:189)
    at scala.reflect.api.Trees$Transformer.transformTrees(Trees.scala:2559)
    at scala.tools.nsc.transform.patmat.PatternMatching$MatchTransformer.transform(PatternMatching.scala:62)
    at scala.tools.nsc.transform.patmat.PatternMatching$MatchTransformer.transform(PatternMatching.scala:57)
    at scala.reflect.internal.Trees$$anonfun$itransform$3.apply(Trees.scala:1379)
    at scala.reflect.internal.Trees$$anonfun$itransform$3.apply(Trees.scala:1379)
    at scala.reflect.api.Trees$Transformer.atOwner(Trees.scala:2600)
    at scala.tools.nsc.transform.TypingTransformers$TypingTransformer.atOwner(TypingTransformers.scala:30)
    at scala.tools.nsc.transform.TypingTransformers$TypingTransformer.atOwner(TypingTransformers.scala:25)
    at scala.tools.nsc.transform.TypingTransformers$TypingTransformer.atOwner(TypingTransformers.scala:17)
    at scala.reflect.internal.Trees$class.itransform(Trees.scala:1378)
    at scala.reflect.internal.SymbolTable.itransform(SymbolTable.scala:16)
    at scala.reflect.internal.SymbolTable.itransform(SymbolTable.scala:16)
    at scala.reflect.api.Trees$Transformer.transform(Trees.scala:2555)
    at scala.tools.nsc.transform.TypingTransformers$TypingTransformer.transform(TypingTransformers.scala:44)
    at scala.tools.nsc.transform.patmat.PatternMatching$MatchTransformer.transform(PatternMatching.scala:73)
    at scala.tools.nsc.transform.patmat.PatternMatching$MatchTransformer.transform(PatternMatching.scala:57)
    at scala.reflect.api.Trees$Transformer$$anonfun$transformTrees$1.apply(Trees.scala:2559)
    at scala.reflect.api.Trees$Transformer$$anonfun$transformTrees$1.apply(Trees.scala:2559)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.loop$1(List.scala:173)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.mapConserve(List.scala:189)
    at scala.reflect.api.Trees$Transformer.transformTrees(Trees.scala:2559)
    at scala.reflect.internal.Trees$class.itransform(Trees.scala:1347)
    at scala.reflect.internal.SymbolTable.itransform(SymbolTable.scala:16)
    at scala.reflect.internal.SymbolTable.itransform(SymbolTable.scala:16)
    at scala.reflect.api.Trees$Transformer.transform(Trees.scala:2555)
    at scala.tools.nsc.transform.TypingTransformers$TypingTransformer.transform(TypingTransformers.scala:44)
    at scala.tools.nsc.transform.patmat.PatternMatching$MatchTransformer.transform(PatternMatching.scala:73)
    at scala.tools.nsc.transform.patmat.PatternMatching$MatchTransformer.transform(PatternMatching.scala:57)
    at scala.reflect.internal.Trees$$anonfun$itransform$2.apply(Trees.scala:1363)
    at scala.reflect.internal.Trees$$anonfun$itransform$2.apply(Trees.scala:1361)
    at scala.reflect.api.Trees$Transformer.atOwner(Trees.scala:2600)
    at scala.tools.nsc.transform.TypingTransformers$TypingTransformer.atOwner(TypingTransformers.scala:30)
    at scala.tools.nsc.transform.TypingTransformers$TypingTransformer.atOwner(TypingTransformers.scala:25)
    at scala.tools.nsc.transform.TypingTransformers$TypingTransformer.atOwner(TypingTransformers.scala:17)
    at scala.reflect.internal.Trees$class.itransform(Trees.scala:1360)
    at scala.reflect.internal.SymbolTable.itransform(SymbolTable.scala:16)
    at scala.reflect.internal.SymbolTable.itransform(SymbolTable.scala:16)
    at scala.reflect.api.Trees$Transformer.transform(Trees.scala:2555)
    at scala.tools.nsc.transform.TypingTransformers$TypingTransformer.transform(TypingTransformers.scala:44)
    at scala.tools.nsc.transform.patmat.PatternMatching$MatchTransformer.transform(PatternMatching.scala:73)
    at scala.tools.nsc.transform.patmat.PatternMatching$MatchTransformer.transform(PatternMatching.scala:57)
    at scala.reflect.api.Trees$Transformer$$anonfun$transformStats$1.apply(Trees.scala:2589)
    at scala.reflect.api.Trees$Transformer$$anonfun$transformStats$1.apply(Trees.scala:2587)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.loop$1(List.scala:173)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.mapConserve(List.scala:189)
    at scala.reflect.api.Trees$Transformer.transformStats(Trees.scala:2587)
    at scala.reflect.internal.Trees$class.itransform(Trees.scala:1404)
    at scala.reflect.internal.SymbolTable.itransform(SymbolTable.scala:16)
    at scala.reflect.internal.SymbolTable.itransform(SymbolTable.scala:16)
    at scala.reflect.api.Trees$Transformer.transform(Trees.scala:2555)
    at scala.tools.nsc.transform.TypingTransformers$TypingTransformer.scala$tools$nsc$transform$TypingTransformers$TypingTransformer$$super$transform(TypingTransformers.scala:40)
    at scala.tools.nsc.transform.TypingTransformers$TypingTransformer$$anonfun$transform$1.apply(TypingTransformers.scala:40)
    at scala.tools.nsc.transform.TypingTransformers$TypingTransformer$$anonfun$transform$1.apply(TypingTransformers.scala:40)
    at scala.reflect.api.Trees$Transformer.atOwner(Trees.scala:2600)
    at scala.tools.nsc.transform.TypingTransformers$TypingTransformer.atOwner(TypingTransformers.scala:30)
    at scala.tools.nsc.transform.TypingTransformers$TypingTransformer.transform(TypingTransformers.scala:40)
    at scala.tools.nsc.transform.patmat.PatternMatching$MatchTransformer.transform(PatternMatching.scala:73)
    at scala.tools.nsc.transform.patmat.PatternMatching$MatchTransformer.transform(PatternMatching.scala:57)
    at scala.reflect.api.Trees$Transformer.transformTemplate(Trees.scala:2563)
    at scala.reflect.internal.Trees$$anonfun$itransform$4.apply(Trees.scala:1408)
    at scala.reflect.internal.Trees$$anonfun$itransform$4.apply(Trees.scala:1407)
    at scala.reflect.api.Trees$Transformer.atOwner(Trees.scala:2600)
    at scala.tools.nsc.transform.TypingTransformers$TypingTransformer.atOwner(TypingTransformers.scala:30)
    at scala.tools.nsc.transform.TypingTransformers$TypingTransformer.atOwner(TypingTransformers.scala:25)
    at scala.tools.nsc.transform.TypingTransformers$TypingTransformer.atOwner(TypingTransformers.scala:17)
    at scala.reflect.internal.Trees$class.itransform(Trees.scala:1406)
    at scala.reflect.internal.SymbolTable.itransform(SymbolTable.scala:16)
    at scala.reflect.internal.SymbolTable.itransform(SymbolTable.scala:16)
    at scala.reflect.api.Trees$Transformer.transform(Trees.scala:2555)
    at scala.tools.nsc.transform.TypingTransformers$TypingTransformer.transform(TypingTransformers.scala:44)
    at scala.tools.nsc.transform.patmat.PatternMatching$MatchTransformer.transform(PatternMatching.scala:73)
    at scala.tools.nsc.transform.patmat.PatternMatching$MatchTransformer.transform(PatternMatching.scala:57)
    at scala.reflect.api.Trees$Transformer$$anonfun$transformStats$1.apply(Trees.scala:2589)
    at scala.reflect.api.Trees$Transformer$$anonfun$transformStats$1.apply(Trees.scala:2587)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.loop$1(List.scala:173)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.mapConserve(List.scala:189)
    at scala.reflect.api.Trees$Transformer.transformStats(Trees.scala:2587)
    at scala.reflect.internal.Trees$$anonfun$itransform$7.apply(Trees.scala:1426)
    at scala.reflect.internal.Trees$$anonfun$itransform$7.apply(Trees.scala:1426)
    at scala.reflect.api.Trees$Transformer.atOwner(Trees.scala:2600)
    at scala.tools.nsc.transform.TypingTransformers$TypingTransformer.atOwner(TypingTransformers.scala:30)
    at scala.tools.nsc.transform.TypingTransformers$TypingTransformer.atOwner(TypingTransformers.scala:25)
    at scala.tools.nsc.transform.TypingTransformers$TypingTransformer.atOwner(TypingTransformers.scala:17)
    at scala.reflect.internal.Trees$class.itransform(Trees.scala:1425)
    at scala.reflect.internal.SymbolTable.itransform(SymbolTable.scala:16)
    at scala.reflect.internal.SymbolTable.itransform(SymbolTable.scala:16)
    at scala.reflect.api.Trees$Transformer.transform(Trees.scala:2555)
    at scala.tools.nsc.transform.TypingTransformers$TypingTransformer.scala$tools$nsc$transform$TypingTransformers$TypingTransformer$$super$transform(TypingTransformers.scala:40)
    at scala.tools.nsc.transform.TypingTransformers$TypingTransformer$$anonfun$transform$2.apply(TypingTransformers.scala:42)
    at scala.tools.nsc.transform.TypingTransformers$TypingTransformer$$anonfun$transform$2.apply(TypingTransformers.scala:42)
    at scala.reflect.api.Trees$Transformer.atOwner(Trees.scala:2600)
    at scala.tools.nsc.transform.TypingTransformers$TypingTransformer.atOwner(TypingTransformers.scala:30)
    at scala.tools.nsc.transform.TypingTransformers$TypingTransformer.transform(TypingTransformers.scala:42)
    at scala.tools.nsc.transform.patmat.PatternMatching$MatchTransformer.transform(PatternMatching.scala:73)
    at scala.tools.nsc.transform.patmat.PatternMatching$MatchTransformer.transform(PatternMatching.scala:57)
    at scala.tools.nsc.ast.Trees$Transformer.transformUnit(Trees.scala:147)
    at scala.tools.nsc.transform.Transform$Phase.apply(Transform.scala:30)
    at scala.tools.nsc.Global$GlobalPhase$$anonfun$applyPhase$1.apply$mcV$sp(Global.scala:441)
    at scala.tools.nsc.Global$GlobalPhase.withCurrentUnit(Global.scala:432)
    at scala.tools.nsc.Global$GlobalPhase.applyPhase(Global.scala:441)
    at scala.tools.nsc.Global$GlobalPhase$$anonfun$run$1.apply(Global.scala:399)
    at scala.tools.nsc.Global$GlobalPhase$$anonfun$run$1.apply(Global.scala:399)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:750)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1202)
    at scala.tools.nsc.Global$GlobalPhase.run(Global.scala:399)
    at scala.tools.nsc.Global$Run.compileUnitsInternal(Global.scala:1500)
    at scala.tools.nsc.Global$Run.compileUnits(Global.scala:1487)
    at scala.tools.nsc.Global$Run.compileSources(Global.scala:1482)
    at scala.tools.nsc.Global$Run.compile(Global.scala:1580)
    at xsbt.CachedCompiler0.run(CompilerInterface.scala:116)
    at xsbt.CachedCompiler0.run(CompilerInterface.scala:95)
    at xsbt.CompilerInterface.run(CompilerInterface.scala:26)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at sbt.compiler.AnalyzingCompiler.call(AnalyzingCompiler.scala:101)
    at sbt.compiler.AnalyzingCompiler.compile(AnalyzingCompiler.scala:47)
    at sbt.compiler.AnalyzingCompiler.compile(AnalyzingCompiler.scala:41)
    at sbt.compiler.MixedAnalyzingCompiler$$anonfun$compileScala$1$1.apply$mcV$sp(MixedAnalyzingCompiler.scala:51)
    at sbt.compiler.MixedAnalyzingCompiler$$anonfun$compileScala$1$1.apply(MixedAnalyzingCompiler.scala:51)
    at sbt.compiler.MixedAnalyzingCompiler$$anonfun$compileScala$1$1.apply(MixedAnalyzingCompiler.scala:51)
    at sbt.compiler.MixedAnalyzingCompiler.timed(MixedAnalyzingCompiler.scala:75)
    at sbt.compiler.MixedAnalyzingCompiler.compileScala$1(MixedAnalyzingCompiler.scala:50)
    at sbt.compiler.MixedAnalyzingCompiler.compile(MixedAnalyzingCompiler.scala:65)
    at sbt.compiler.IC$$anonfun$compileInternal$1.apply(IncrementalCompiler.scala:160)
    at sbt.compiler.IC$$anonfun$compileInternal$1.apply(IncrementalCompiler.scala:160)
    at sbt.inc.IncrementalCompile$$anonfun$doCompile$1.apply(Compile.scala:66)
    at sbt.inc.IncrementalCompile$$anonfun$doCompile$1.apply(Compile.scala:64)
    at sbt.inc.IncrementalCommon.cycle(IncrementalCommon.scala:31)
    at sbt.inc.Incremental$$anonfun$1.apply(Incremental.scala:62)
    at sbt.inc.Incremental$$anonfun$1.apply(Incremental.scala:61)
    at sbt.inc.Incremental$.manageClassfiles(Incremental.scala:89)
    at sbt.inc.Incremental$.compile(Incremental.scala:61)
    at sbt.inc.IncrementalCompile$.apply(Compile.scala:54)
    at sbt.compiler.IC$.compileInternal(IncrementalCompiler.scala:160)
    at sbt.compiler.IC$.incrementalCompile(IncrementalCompiler.scala:138)
    at sbt.Compiler$.compile(Compiler.scala:128)
    at sbt.Compiler$.compile(Compiler.scala:114)
    at sbt.Defaults$.sbt$Defaults$$compileIncrementalTaskImpl(Defaults.scala:814)
    at sbt.Defaults$$anonfun$compileIncrementalTask$1.apply(Defaults.scala:805)
    at sbt.Defaults$$anonfun$compileIncrementalTask$1.apply(Defaults.scala:803)
    at scala.Function1$$anonfun$compose$1.apply(Function1.scala:47)
    at sbt.$tilde$greater$$anonfun$$u2219$1.apply(TypeFunctions.scala:40)
    at sbt.std.Transform$$anon$4.work(System.scala:63)
    at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Execute.scala:226)
    at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Execute.scala:226)
    at sbt.ErrorHandling$.wideConvert(ErrorHandling.scala:17)
    at sbt.Execute.work(Execute.scala:235)
    at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1.apply(Execute.scala:226)
    at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1.apply(Execute.scala:226)
    at sbt.ConcurrentRestrictions$$anon$4$$anonfun$1.apply(ConcurrentRestrictions.scala:159)
    at sbt.CompletionService$$anon$2.call(CompletionService.scala:28)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
[error] (compile:compileIncremental) java.lang.NullPointerException
[error] application - 

! @6mhdajb8l - Internal server error, for (GET) [/] ->

play.sbt.PlayExceptions$UnexpectedException: Unexpected exception[NullPointerException: null]
    at play.sbt.run.PlayReload$$anonfun$taskFailureHandler$1.apply(PlayReload.scala:51) ~[na:na]
    at play.sbt.run.PlayReload$$anonfun$taskFailureHandler$1.apply(PlayReload.scala:44) ~[na:na]
    at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:145) ~[scala-library-2.11.6.jar:na]
    at play.sbt.run.PlayReload$.taskFailureHandler(PlayReload.scala:44) ~[na:na]
    at play.sbt.run.PlayReload$.compileFailure(PlayReload.scala:40) ~[na:na]
    at play.sbt.run.PlayReload$$anonfun$compile$1.apply(PlayReload.scala:17) ~[na:na]
    at play.sbt.run.PlayReload$$anonfun$compile$1.apply(PlayReload.scala:17) ~[na:na]
    at scala.util.Either$LeftProjection.map(Either.scala:377) ~[scala-library-2.11.6.jar:na]
    at play.sbt.run.PlayReload$.compile(PlayReload.scala:17) ~[na:na]
    at play.sbt.run.PlayRun$$anonfun$playRunTask$1$$anonfun$apply$2$$anonfun$apply$3$$anonfun$2.apply(PlayRun.scala:60) ~[na:na]
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at scala.tools.nsc.transform.patmat.ScalacPatternExpanders$ScalacPatternExpander$class.applyMethodTypes(ScalacPatternExpanders.scala:64) ~[scala-compiler-2.11.2.jar:na]
    at scala.tools.nsc.transform.patmat.ScalacPatternExpanders$alignPatterns$.applyMethodTypes(ScalacPatternExpanders.scala:90) ~[scala-compiler-2.11.2.jar:na]
    at scala.tools.nsc.transform.patmat.ScalacPatternExpanders$alignPatterns$.apply(ScalacPatternExpanders.scala:132) ~[scala-compiler-2.11.2.jar:na]
    at scala.tools.nsc.transform.patmat.ScalacPatternExpanders$alignPatterns$.apply(ScalacPatternExpanders.scala:153) ~[scala-compiler-2.11.2.jar:na]
    at scala.tools.nsc.transform.patmat.MatchTranslation$MatchTranslator$ExtractorCall$.apply(MatchTranslation.scala:384) ~[scala-compiler-2.11.2.jar:na]
    at scala.tools.nsc.transform.patmat.MatchTranslation$MatchTranslator$BoundTree.extractor$lzycompute(MatchTranslation.scala:71) ~[scala-compiler-2.11.2.jar:na]
    at scala.tools.nsc.transform.patmat.MatchTranslation$MatchTranslator$BoundTree.extractor(MatchTranslation.scala:71) ~[scala-compiler-2.11.2.jar:na]
    at scala.tools.nsc.transform.patmat.MatchTranslation$MatchTranslator$BoundTree.paramType$1(MatchTranslation.scala:113) ~[scala-compiler-2.11.2.jar:na]
    at scala.tools.nsc.transform.patmat.MatchTranslation$MatchTranslator$BoundTree.extractorStep(MatchTranslation.scala:129) ~[scala-compiler-2.11.2.jar:na]
    at scala.tools.nsc.transform.patmat.MatchTranslation$MatchTranslator$BoundTree.nextStep(MatchTranslation.scala:151) ~[scala-compiler-2.11.2.jar:na]
```

UPDATE: I found that the cause was that I had: (where res is the future that was created from an akka "ask")

```
res.map {
          case Accountant.OrderPlaced(order) =>
            Created(Json.toJson(order))
          case Failure(e) =>
            BadRequest(e.toString)
        }
```

but had changed it to:

```
res.map {
          case Accountant.OrderPlaced(order) =>
            Created(Json.toJson(order))
          case Status.Failure(e) =>
            BadRequest(e.toString)
        }
```

It's not clear to me why this caused this issue. On a failure, my actor sends back an akka.actor.Status.Failure, and I have both

```
import akka.actor._
import akka.actor.Status.Failure
```

in my imports, so I would have thought the two code fragments above are equivalent?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a different `Failure` was indadvertedly used. For example, a search in Play 2.4 for Failure yields the following list of possibilities:

[image]